# Input Text into Website using CEFSHARP from Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use CEFSHARP to auto-login to a website and I'm using this code:

```
Dim jsScript As String = <js><![CDATA[document.all("login-email").value = 'TextBox1.Text';]]></js>.Value
Dim jsScript2 As String = <js><![CDATA[document.all("login-password").value = 'TextBox2.Text';]]></js>.Value

Await browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript)
Await browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript2)
```

It should put my `TextBox`'s text into the website, but it just inputs "TextBox1.text" and not the actual string I want.

How can I insert the value of `TextBox1.Text` into the string?

Answer (score 0):

The statements are too complex to be able to use XML Literals.

Try string interpolation instead:

```
Dim jsScript As String = $"<js><![CDATA[document.all(""login-email"").value = '{TextBox1.Text}';]]></js>.Value"
```

Comment: The `.Value` on the XML literal returns the inner text, so `jsScript` only contains the  contents of CDATA (`document.all("").value = ''`). At which point it's not clear why XML literals were used in the first place - I assume to perform HTML escaping of the textbox value.

Comment: This was the only code i could find and be able to put a string into the website, that's why i used this code in first place, but still it doesn't work..

Comment: @NickyJam ~ The snippet in my answer works—the value of `TextBox1.Text` is inserted into the string. You'll want to ditch XML Literals for your case and use String Interpolation instead.